# Benchmarking C bubblesort performance compared to Julia

Tags: c, performance, julia

I wanted to create a formal comparison between C and Julia performance. For this purpose I wanted to compare different sorting algorithms, starting with the bubble. In Julia I wrote it like:

```
using BenchmarkTools

function bubble_sort(v::AbstractArray{T}) where T<:Real
    for _ in 1:length(v)-1
        for i in 1:length(v)-1
            if v[i] > v[i+1]
                v[i], v[i+1] = v[i+1], v[i]
            end
        end
    end
    return v
end

v = rand(Int32, 100_000)
@timed bubble_sort(_v)
```

In the case of C code (I don't know to program in C so I apologize for the code):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static void swap(int *xp, int *yp){
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

void bubble_sort(int arr[], int n){
    int i, j;
    for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++){
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
            if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]){
                swap(&arr[i], &arr[i+1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int arr_sz = 100000;
    int arr[arr_sz], i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr_sz; i++){
        arr[i] = rand();
    }
    double cpu_time_used;
    clock_t begin = clock();
    bubble_sort(arr, arr_sz);
    clock_t end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - begin)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("time %f\n", cpu_time_used);
    return 0;
}
```

The performance difference is (in my computer):

| Julia | C |
| --- | --- |
| 20s | ~50s |

I suppose that I have a big mistake in the C code, but I am not able to find it out, or is just Julia faster in loops?

## Update: performance optimization

- Changed the type to int32 in Julia so it is the same as C
- `swap` method as static (+1s improvement on average)
- compiling optimization (detailed bellow)

Instead of `gcc main.c`, I've used different optimization flags, as also the clang compiler. Results:

|  | Time (s) |
| --- | --- |
| Julia | 19.13 |
| `gcc -O main.c` | 47.58 |
| `gcc -O1 main.c` | 15.98 |
| `gcc -O2 main.c` | 19.52 |
| `gcc -O3 main.c` | 19.20 |
| `gcc -Os main.c` | 17.72 |
| `clang -O0 main.c` | 51.59 |
| `clang -O1 main.c` | 16.78 |
| `clang -O2 main.c` | 13.53 |
| `clang -O3 main.c` | 13.57 |
| `clang -Ofast main.c` | 12.39 |
| `clang -Os main.c` | 18.85 |
| `clang -Oz main.c` | 15.64 |
| `clang -Og main.c` | 16.37 |

Comment: You ***are*** compiling with all compiler optimizations enabled, aren't you?

Comment: @AndrewHenle You were wight, I changed the compilation for `gcc -o main -O main.c` and it is faster now, thanks

Comment: `static void swap(int *xp, int *yp){...}` could make a lot of difference. (or just: inline)

Comment: In general, GCC (and clang) only really start optimising properly with `-O2`. Using `-O` (or equivalently `-O1`) won’t do nearly as much, and isn’t sufficient for a benchmark (or real-world usage, when performance counts) — although *in this particular case* it actually seems that the current version of GCC at least does fine with just `-O1`.

Comment: FWIW it looks like you are comparing apples to oranges. Julia code is sorting Int64, while your C program is likely using 32-bit integers.

Comment: Not a problem, I tried both in Julia with no changes in performance.

Comment: `void swap(int *xp, int *yp)` is a keypoint, in julia you don't have a subroutine call (with all relative overhead). You **must** inline the code to obtain closest performance. And also the sample distribution is influent, you should use the same sample.

Comment: Also, you are using different inputs. Sorting algorithms can have drastic differences in performances for different inputs.

Comment: Keep in mind that the OS you build and run your executable on will have an effect in terms of both run-time _and_ consistency of run-times between tests.  ( [reference](https://www.bitsnbites.eu/benchmarking-os-primitives/) )

Comment: use `-O3` or `-Ofast` not `-O` as it does not enable any more aggressive optimizations.

Comment: @Frankie_C it is not. gcc will inline it itself.

Comment: @0___________ Unfortunately `-O3` is not always faster than `-O2`; in some cases it can even result in *slower* code. There are studies comparing the two settings across large samples of code, and (admittedly, as of ~10 years ago) `-O2` was on average *slightly faster* than `-O3`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You are right Test: `-O0` time 40.925213, `-O1` time 15.323867,  `-O2` time 18.280225,  `-O3` time 28.776320, `-Os` time 18.924069. Just tested this program on my machine

Comment: @0___________, Did you modify the program to use the same inputs for all runs, or are those number worthless?

Comment: The slower `-O3` implementation is typically due to the vectorization (using SSE) of the inner loop by GCC which is a good idea only if the condition is often wrong. In practice, it is certainly not the case causing a near double check (hence the near double time).

Comment: @ikegami the radom data was generated as 'C' file. compiled and linked. Same data every time

Comment: @0___________, The data is an array of floats. I don't know what you mean by generating an array of floats "as C file". If you used a different array of floats for the different runs (as the OP's code does), the numbers you gave are useless.

Comment: The array is machine generated C file int x[] = {....}. It is compiled and statically linked with the file. The array is actually int not float. The data **is the same**

Comment: @0___________, Cool, thanks :)

Comment: @DecowVR can you update the question with 1) the exact command line; 2) the timing of the C version with optimized flags; fix the C implementation so it uses `int64_t` types. 4) the time using the Clang compiler and not GCC. The last point is the most important.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I updated the post, Im working on the clang part

Comment: @JérômeRichard clang added. Awesome results.

Comment: Indeed, as expected. The Julia backend (JIT compiler) is based on the LLVM like Clang. Clang can do more aggressive optimization than Julia because the JIT should not take too much time to compile a program (otherwise the runtime compilation time could huge compare to the computation time). This is why It would be surprising to see Julia slower than Clang. However, GCC can be slower than Clang and so than Julia too in pathological cases. The speed of GCC vs Clang strongly depends of the target code. Here, GCC make a wrong optimizing assumption not made by Clang.

Comment: Would you add `-Ofast` for `GCC` as well?

Comment: After adding an `@inbounds` before the `if` statement in the function, and measuring things with `v` locally scoped as `let v = rand(Int32, 100_000);   @btime(bubble_sort($v)); end`, I get 8.7s as the time for the Julia code (on a laptop where `gcc -Os` of this C code takes 26s). Could anyone else report what numbers they get and how the comparison fares with these changes? (Runnable code at https://gist.github.com/digital-carver/35730613c98d441629c3ba4b98b20758)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this question may have been reopened after you discovered that your initial measurements were taken on code compiled for debugging, rather than fully optimised, with different sets of data, different compiler platforms and different integer representations.

> I suppose that I have a big mistake in the C code, but I am not able to find it out, or is just Julia faster in loops?

I can answer this somewhat cringy (in my opinion) double-barreled question with [a quote from the C standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p1): "The semantic descriptions in this International Standard describe the behavior of an abstract machine in which issues of optimization are irrelevant." In short, there's no *speed* in C; that's an attribute that occurs in *implementations* of C. We can't reproduce your *speed* without having your *implementation* (including your hardware, for example).

It's very possible that Julia has similar clauses in her spec. The gist is: some nifty optimisations may determine that your sorted arrays don't have any *necessary side-effects* and so those may theoretically be optimised away. I'd expect both programs to output somewhere near 0.0 in that case. This is your *perfectly optimal* compiler; one that spots code that has no actual impact upon the logic of the program, and *optimises away the dead code*.

We haven't always had loop-invariant code motion, and so it stands to reason that there may be a fifth element here: your compilers version. You'll probably get different statistics if the underlying llvm is different, for example:

> LLVM 11 tends to take 2x longer to compile code with optimizations, and as a result produces code that runs 10-20% faster (with occasional outliers in either direction), compared to LLVM 2.7 which is more than 10 years old.

-- [source](https://gist.github.com/zeux/3ce4fcc3a43072b4315abde95319ecb6)

Perhaps one day you'll update this question with output that reads 0.0s for both programs. Then this question has truly lost its point.

---

It's hard to tell what further is being asked here, @cbk. The comments section managed to reduce the runtime for the C program significantly with those four improvements. The question kinda doesn't even make sense here anymore, because it largely cancels itself out by answering itself at the end.

Perhaps this is just one of those cases where a newcomer ought to have answered their own question *with an answer* (you can do that), rather than rotting the question with edits that answer it... Nonetheless, it's a question that now shows up unanswered in the list of questions. I'd vote to close for the reason "The question should include more details", but I suspect then you might include an example of compilation halted after assembly generation, when OP seems to have glossed over the solution, the details we need are more along the lines of "What didn't you understand about these comments that answer your original question?" and yet the question has varied so much in apparent meaning... Are we gonna have a close/reopen war?